# having the geolocation code fire every time the page is visited not just on initial load or refresh

Tags: javascript, cordova, jquery-mobile, geolocation

The following code i have on my index.html page of my app

each time the app is started or the index page refreshed the code loads the co ordinates and appends to the urls attached to the button on the page

however if i simply return to the home page from another page within the app the code below does not refresh and there are no co ordinates appended to the buttons

how do i modify the code so that each time the page loads the code below runs and therefore appends the current co ordinates to the buttons on the page

```
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

            // Wait for device API libraries to load
            //
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

            // device APIs are available
            //
            function onDeviceReady() {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
            }

        function changeLinksAddCoords( lat, long ) {
            $('.toChange').each( function(index) {
                                var el = $(this);

                                var href = el.attr('href');
                                href +=  lat + ',' + long
                                el.attr('href', href);
                                });
        }

        // onSuccess Geolocation
        //
        function onSuccess(position) {
            var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');
            changeLinksAddCoords( position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude)
            element.innerHTML = + position.coords.latitude + ',' + position.coords.longitude;
        }

        // onError Callback receives a PositionError object
        //
        function onError(error) {
            alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
                  'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
        }

            </script>
```

Comment: you already have the answer here: [migrate from jquerymobile 1.2.1 to 1.4.5](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38540706/4845566)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you tagged jquery-mobile because you are using it, handle the pagecontainer's beforeshow event:

http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#event-beforeshow

This event triggers every time you visit the page.